# Remove tab focus for tabPanel in sencha touch

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, tabpanel

How do I remove the focus of any tab on a tabPanel in Sencha Touch? I am opening up a different dialog that does not have a tab in the tabPanel, and I want to represent that so that the user doesn't get confused. How do I do this? Calling `views.tabPanel.setActiveItem(-1)` and `views.tabPanel.setActiveItem(null)` don't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think , for tabpanel, it is also require one and only one tab active.

Not sure. I'm also a newbie to js and sencha touch.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, for Sencha Touch 2 I've implemented the following. **Note** however, that it is a workaround, so take it with a grain of salt.

In my app.js

```
...
setActiveTab: function(idOfTabToActiveOrNull) {
  var tb = Ext.Viewport.getDockedComponent('your-tabbar-id');
  if (tb && !idOfTabToActiveOrNull) {
    var at = an.getActiveTab();
    if (at) { at.setActive(false); }
    // Note that this only changes style, but the tab is still "active" in the tabbar
  } else if (an) {
    tb.setActiveTab(idOfTabToActiveOrNull);
    tb.getActiveTab().setActive(true); // just to be sure it's marked
  }
},
...
```

Use it like this:

```
YourApp.app.setActiveTab(null); // remove styles for active tab
YourApp.app.setActiveTab('id-of-other-tab'); // change to different tab
```